# How to add multiple classes and attributes to rails button_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm quite new to rails and I was trying somehow add all the attributes and classes I have into the button_to within the button_to because at the moment it's adding a silver button box on top of my actual button, so I don't know how to actually combine the multiple classes above within it.

```
   <button class="class1" data-method="dl" data-option="dl" type="button" title="Dl">
        <span class="class2" data-placement="bottom" title="Dl">
                <span class="icon">
                    <%= button_to proof_path(@param) %>
                </span>
        </span>
    </button>
```

link_to won't work because I want the actual button to be clickable and not text.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass stuff into the button_to in a block

ex.

```
<%= button_to [:make_happy, @user] do %>
  Make <strong><%= @user.name %></strong> happy
<% end %>
```

you can put icons and what not in that block...

ref: [Docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly how I went about solving this issue!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to nest a button within a button which is invalid html. First step is to use only one button.  Second step is to use [button_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) to set all of the html attributes that you need.

Ex

```
button_to("Button Text", proof_path(@param), {},
          data: {method: "dl, option: "dl"}, class: "class1")
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know this,  also used a block after to make it more readable, as stated in the answer above.